# file owner can not change ownership in Linux

Tags: linux

In Linux, I am the owner of a file, then I tried to change owner to another account, failed. Operation not permitted. Do you know why ? I am the user 'BBB'. Thanks

```
-bash-4.1$ ls -al
drwxrwxrwx 2 AAA games      4096 Nov 23 14:39 .
drwxr-xr-x 3 AAA games      4096 Nov 23 14:36 ..
-rw-r--r-- 1 BBB esmgroup  16798 Nov 23 14:38 XXX-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
-bash-4.1$ chown AAA:games ./*.jar
chown: changing ownership of `./XXX-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar': Operation not permitted
```

Comment: Use `sudo`. Such actions require `sudo` or elevated permisions.

Comment: `chown` needs to be run with `sudo`. e.g. `sudo chown newuser XXX-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar`

Comment: but tried the sudo, BBB is not in the sudo user list

Answer (score 0):

Only root can change the owner on the file. That's final.

You can do that by login to root using `su` or use `sudo` before your command.

More information here: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/27350/why-cant-a-normal-user-chown-a-file

You can change the file's group if you're in more than one group.

Answer (score 0):

You should login to root account to be granted to change ownership to any user

You can type sudo before the command and then login to your root user